# Angular 2 spec test for a component using material design

Tags: angular, testing, material-design

I would like to test a component that uses material design and has a title.

```
<md-card-title>{{title}}</md-card-title>
```

How can I query the element containing the title?

```
it('should display original title', () => {

    // trigger change detection to update the view
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // query for the title by what ???
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By ???('md-card-title'));

    // confirm the element's content
    expect(de.nativeElement.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use one of these methods:

```
import { MdCardTitle } from '@angular/material';

de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MdCardTitle));
```

or

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('md-card-title'));
```